# Tensorflow GPU on EC2 instance using google colab notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I have launched a "Deep Learning AMI GPU TensorFlow" EC2 instance.
Then I am connecting it to a google colab (jupyter) notebook to run my code from there. It is all working fine at this point.
I need to run code on `tensorflow-gpu`. But it seems not available, I have run the following:

```
tf.test.is _built_with_cuda()
True
tf.test.is _gpu_available()
False
```

As a result I have installed CUDA on the linux instance using the command specified here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local

But that didn't solved it. I think cuda should already be installed as it is a "GPU" instance so I am wondering how to activate it and to run tensorflow-gpu from the connected colab notebook.

Comment: an instance is a machine type.  An AMI is a software image.  The thing you have mentioned is an AMI.  You need to indicate what instance type you have launched this AMI on.  If the instance doesn't have a GPU, then you can't do GPU work in that instance.  Of course, if you connect to google colab from that instance or any other machine, you can use GPUs provided by colab.  That has nothing to do with your machine.